# Protocol-relative urls in Django Compressor's manifest.json

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles, django-compressor

I am using [Django Compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) with offline compression and store the compressed static files on Amazon S3. My problem is that `manifest.json` references cached files by specifying `http://` as protocol:

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" 
 href=\"http://stage-media.dropspot-app.com.s3.amazonaws.com/static/CACHE/css/abffb776bf3e.css\" 
 type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\" /><link rel=\"stylesheet\" 
 href=\"http://stage-media.dropspot-app.com.s3.amazonaws.com/static/CACHE/css/9533603cdbaa.css\"     
 type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" 
/>
```

This results in cached files not being loaded when the page is accessed via HTTPS:

`The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/static/CACHE/css/abffb776bf3e.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

The solution would be to have `manifest.json` referencing the cached files without having the `http:` in the urls, but have not found a way to have it generated this way.

Is there is a way to generate `manifest.json` with protocol-relative urls?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but i spent a lot of time trying to fix it recently.
This confiuration will make `django-compress` generate protocol-relative urls in both the manifest and compress tag:

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = ''
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = "//%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` is important for backward-compatibility, this will not work if omitted.